# Custom url helper method in presenter causing test error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I'm writing tests for a presenter class and am getting the following error when running them, coming from a custom url helper method.

```
Error:
PersonPresenterTest#test_0011_should get email icon:
ArgumentError: arguments passed to url_for can't be handled. Please require routes or provide your own implementation
app/helpers/people_helper.rb:4:in `link_fa_to'
app/presenters/base_presenter.rb:14:in `method_missing'
app/presenters/person_presenter.rb:54:in `email_icon'
test/presenters/person_presenter_test.rb:59:in `block in <class:PersonPresenterTest>'
```

**person_presenter_test.rb**

```
 class PersonPresenterTest < ActionView::TestCase
  add_template_helper(PeopleHelper)

  def setup
    @person = FactoryGirl.create(:person)
    @presenter = PersonPresenter.new(@person, view)
  end

  test 'should get email icon' do
    expected = '<a class="icon-link" href="/people/1"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-1x"></i></a>'
    actual = @presenter.email_icon
    assert_equal(expected, actual)
  end
end
```

**person_presenter.rb**

```
class PersonPresenter < BasePresenter
  presents :person

  def email_icon
    link_fa_to('envelope fa-1x', person) if person.email.present?
  end
end
```

**base_presenter.rb**

```
class BasePresenter
  def initialize(object, template)
    @object = object
    @template = template
  end

  def self.presents(name)
    define_method(name) do
      @object
    end
  end

  def method_missing(*args, &block)
    @template.send(*args, &block)
  end
end
```

**people_helper.rb**

```
module PeopleHelper

  def link_fa_to(icon_name, link)
    link_to content_tag(:i, '', class: "fa fa-#{icon_name}"), link, class: "icon-link"
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :organisations
  resources :people
  resources :reset_password, only: [:edit, :update, :new, :index, :create]
  resources :dashboards, only: [:index]
  resources :users

  get 'profile' => 'users#show', as: :profile

  controller :sessions do
    get 'login' => :new
    post 'login' => :create
  end

  get '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
  get "sessions/create"
  get 'sessions' => "sessions#destroy", as: :logout

  root 'sessions#new'
end
```

I can test presenter methods which use `link_to` successfully, and would expect methods calling `link_fa_to` to 'fall' through to the template in the same way. This is only affecting tests, the method works perfectly when running the application.

Any help much appreciated.

**edit:**

If I remove `add_template_helper(PeopleHelper)` from `person_presenter_test.rb`, the error is:

```
Error:
PersonPresenterTest#test_0011_should get email icon:
NoMethodError: undefined method `link_fa_to' for #<#<Class:0x007fcdb6bb19e0>:0x007fcdb6bb15a8>
Did you mean?  link_to
app/presenters/base_presenter.rb:14:in `method_missing'
app/presenters/person_presenter.rb:54:in `email_icon'
test/presenters/person_presenter_test.rb:58:in `block in <class:PersonPresenterTest>'
```

**edit 2:**
After updating `people_helper.rb` to the following in response to Shishir's answer, the error message remains the same:

```
module PeopleHelper

  def link_fa_to(icon_name, link)
    link_to link, class: "icon-link" do
      content_tag(:i, '', class: "fa fa-#{icon_name}")
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `content_tag` returns a string (actually it's an `ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer`, but you can handle it like a string), so that's not your problem.

It seems that you are calling your helper method with an instance of ActiveRecord::Base instead of an url:

`link_fa_to('envelope fa-1x', person) if person.email.present?`

vs:

```
def link_fa_to(icon_name, link)
    link_to content_tag(:i, '', class: "fa fa-#{icon_name}"), link, class: "icon-link"
end
```

You could try to update your code to something like this:

`link_fa_to('envelope fa-1x', person_path(person)) if person.email.present?`

Comment: Perfect explanation. I'll apply the bounty when I can. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of link_to you are using doesn't accept content_tag as parameter. It only accepts string.

```
link_to content_tag(:i, '', class: "fa fa-#{icon_name}"), link, class: "icon-link"
```

Try

```
link_to link do
  content_tag(:i, '', class: "fa fa-#{icon_name}")  
end
```

Comment: I think you may be on the right track, however, I've made your suggested edits (edit 2) and the error message is the same. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you update code for BasePresenter it seems both BasePresenter and PersonPersenter code is the same in the Question?  Can you also link routes.rb?